# Activate the applications on ONOS in GNS3

Tags: command-line-interface, sh, onos

I am using ONOS in GNS3, in the ONOS CLI, I am not able to activate the applications.

After typing the command

`~/onos # app activate org.onosproject.fwd`

It gives an error

`sh: app: not found`

Comment: How to access ONOS CLI in GNS3?

Answer (score 0):

You should connect to the `ONOS CLI` from another computer that has access to the ONOS node through SSH and then run the app activation command.

You can check the list of ONOS Utility scripts for [Remote CLI Monitoring](https://wiki.onosproject.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1048691#AppendixA:ListofONOSUtilityScripts(onos-*scripts)-RemoteCLIMonitoring). (To use them you should have the ONOS repository downloaded, sourced ONOS's bashrc and connection to the ONOS container)

Comment: As soon as I open ONOS console the CLI does not appear, though it says that `Onos-1 console is now available... Press RETURN to get started.`